# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by output started at /home/nyehfdcj/public_html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php:16

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have trouble with my code

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('m_login');
    }
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('admin/v_login');
    }
    function auth(){
        $username=strip_tags(str_replace("'", "", $this->input->post('username')));
        $password=strip_tags(str_replace("'", "", $this->input->post('password')));
        $u=$username;
        $p=$password;
        $cadmin=$this->m_login->cekadmin($u,$p);
        echo json_encode($cadmin);
        if($cadmin->num_rows() > 0){
         $this->session->set_userdata('masuk',true);
         $this->session->set_userdata('user',$u);
         $xcadmin=$cadmin->row_array();
```

And the result is

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/nyehfdcj/public_html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php:16)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: /home/nyehfdcj/public_html/application/controllers/admin/Login.php
Line: 27
Function: redirect

File: /home/nyehfdcj/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: why are you echoing `$cadmin`? what happen if you comment `echo json_encode($cadmin);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like when you are going to set session you are getting those errors. set session in path in your config.php

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH.'sessions';
```

may it work for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that whenever you're executing `echo` the header `200` gets sent automatically. This is because the server is responding to a request successfully. It could get conflicted with another different header that you could have sent.

Having this into account, once the header is set and sent, we can't set and send another header i.e. `301`.

To solve this you need to verify along the flow you've pasted that the headers don't get sent twice at any moment.

Greetings,
Matt